# Delphi XE6 Firemonkey TMediaPlayer - delay in sound play

Tags: delphi, audio, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I just simply want to play audio file when the button is clicked. I made simply code and when I clicking the button, the sound appears in about 1 second delay, I want to hear it immediately, any suggestion ?

```
   procedure TForm1.btnSound(Sender: TObject);
   begin
       S:='C:\click.wav';
       mediaplayer1.FileName:=S;
       mediaplayer1.play;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

For short sounds use the native platform APIs:

```
uses
 MMSystem;

function playsound(filename: string);
begin
 sndPlaySound(Pchar(filename), SND_NODEFAULT Or SND_ASYNC);
end;
```

If you want code for the other platforms as well there is a library which does that [here](http://www.fmxexpress.com/free-game-audio-manager-wrapper-class-in-delphi-xe6-firemonkey-for-android-ios-windows-and-osx/).